# Container color does not fill the whole container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to fill my whole container with a particular color, but i am unable to write the code as to how to fill it

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div className="container-fluid d-flex h-100 flex-column" class="p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-dark">
        <div className="row bg-light flex-fill d-flex justify-content-start">
          <div className="col-20 mx-auto col-md-8 mt-4 mb-4 custom-row-bg">
            <h2 className="text-center text-uppercase">input todo</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This only fills up 1/3 of a page, but i want the color to fill up the whole page

[image]

I want the ash color all throughout the page

Comment: I don't get your problem. I tried on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdknmuz1/) but it fill the color the whole container

Comment: I need to get that color to my whole page , i have eddited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this live [example](https://jsfiddle.net/x47gt9o2/1/)

I just change `bg-dark text-light` to be the change obsiously!